# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty form_for :method=>"get"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm getting an error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" for

```
<%= form_for @assessment, :method=>"get", :url => url_for(:action => 'new') do |f| %>
```

I get the error when re-rendering the :options page after an invalid submission.  What's wrong with the way I've set this up?

Step 1: User needs to choose a template and a patient_id in Assessment#Options

```
 def options
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.new
    @patients = current_user.patients.sort_by{|e| e.first_name.downcase}
    @patient = current_user.patients.new
    @templates = Template.all
  end
```

Assessment#options view:

```
<%= form_for @assessment, :method=>"get", :url => url_for(:action => 'new') do |f| %>

      <% if @assessment.errors.any? %>
        <div>
          <%= pluralize(@assessment.errors.count, "error") %> prevented the account from being created:
          <ul>
            <% @assessment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
              <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

...

  <%= f.submit "Create Assessment", :class => "btn btn-primary", :style=>"width:100%;", :id=>"options-submit" %>


<% end %>
```

On submit, I GET this action:

```
 def new
    if params[:assessment][:template_id].present? && params[:assessment][:patient_id].present?
      @assessment = current_user.assessments.new
      @assessment.template = Template.find(params[:template_id])
      @assessment.patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:patient_id])
    else
      render :options
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `@assessment` to be instantiated.  You can move it outside the condition.

```
  def new
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.new
    if params[:assessment][:template_id].present? && params[:assessment][:patient_id].present?
      @assessment.template = Template.find(params[:template_id])
      @assessment.patient = current_user.patients.find(params[:patient_id])
    else
      render :options
    end
  end
```

Comment: But if user submitted the form with errors, then I wanted to render the :options page with the original @assessment object so that I could highlight the errors..  ( <% if @assessment.errors.any? %>)

Comment: Wouldn't instantiating a new @assessment object be like starting from scratch?

Comment: When you render, it will just render the view, it won't call the controller method with that name.  If that's what you need to do, you can call `options; render :options`.

Comment: BTW - what is options?  Is that an action or a partial?

Comment: options is an action where user selects a few options that are required before rendering the #new action. Is that bad practice?

Comment: I just had something like this and I used `new` to do it.  I showed the ui to select if the param was missing.  If it was there (in the url), I show the form.  You can generate the same instance variables that way.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
render :options
```

does not execute the action options in your controller.  It only renders the view using the variables in the new action.  As a result none of your instance variables are actually being being set, so your form craps out.

Try moving the stuff in the options method into your if-then loop.